# Parallel Table dont use Paralization after long calculation

Tags: parallelization

at first: This is my first post and I hope you understand me. If I made any mistakes how to write a question please feel free to correct me. Now to the question.

I wrote a module which evaluates a Parallel Table and sum all entries.

```
calIntE222[para_,vecA_,vecB_]:=Module[{NMax = para["NMax3D"],res = 0,n1,n2,n3,L = getLengthInNat[para["L"]],actXn,mQ = para["mQ"],tab,actXnAbs},
    tab = ParallelTable[
            If[n1==0 && n2==0 && n3==0,0,
                actXn = {L*n1,L*n2,L*n3};
                actXnAbs = L*Sqrt[n1^2+n2^2+n3^2];
                (((mQ (vecA.actXn)(vecB.actXn))/actXnAbs^4)BesselK[4,actXnAbs*mQ]-vecA.vecB/actXnAbs^3 BesselK[3,actXnAbs*mQ])
            ]
            ,{n1,-NMax,NMax},{n2,-NMax,NMax},{n3,-NMax,NMax},Method->"CoarsestGrained"];
    res = (Total[Total[Total[tab]]] * mQ^3)/(4 \[Pi]^2);
    ClearAll[tab,actXn,actXnAbs];
    Return[res];
]
```

I have to evaluate this Module for over 1000 different combination of the vectors a and b. During this calculation I noticed the following:

The longer the Mathematica Script runs the longer the evaluation of the modules takes. At first the evaluation needs about 0.8s and at the end about 4 to 5 seconds. If I abort the calculation and try it again the evaluation time is still about 4 to 5 seconds. Only if I quit and restart the kernel, the evaluation time is again 0.8s.
I tried the following:

- Clear all variables in the module
- set $HistoryLength=0

But nothing works. I also take a look at the CPU usage of my Ubuntu. It seems that at the first minutes all four cores run with at least 80%. But after a certain time only one kernel remains working with 80% and the other are under 15%. So is this a Mathematica issue and I have to initialize the sub kernels on a specific way or is this a problem with Ubuntu? I searched the last two days for answers but haven't find anything. Maybe anyone here have a solution? I attache a short standalone Mathematica script which highlights the problem

```
getLengthInNat[len_] := Module[{fak,h,c},

   fak = SetPrecision[0.1973269804,20]; (*Produkt h*c aus der paricel data group*)
   Return[len/fak];
];
Print["1fm == ",getLengthInNat[1], " GeV^(-1)"];

massSetNat = Association["MD" -> 1.232, "MN" -> 0.938919, "mPi" ->  0.13957]; (*Massen  in GeV*)

calIntE222[para_,vecA_,vecB_]:=Module[{NMax = para["NMax3D"],res = 0,n1,n2,n3,L = getLengthInNat[para["L"]],actXn,mQ = para["mQ"],tab,actXnAbs},
    tab = ParallelTable[
            If[n1==0 && n2==0 && n3==0,0,
                actXn = {L*n1,L*n2,L*n3};
                actXnAbs = L*Sqrt[n1^2+n2^2+n3^2];
                (((mQ (vecA.actXn)(vecB.actXn))/actXnAbs^4)BesselK[4,actXnAbs*mQ]-vecA.vecB/actXnAbs^3 BesselK[3,actXnAbs*mQ])
            ]
            ,{n1,-NMax,NMax},{n2,-NMax,NMax},{n3,-NMax,NMax},Method->"CoarsestGrained"];
    res = (Total[Total[Total[tab]]] * mQ^3)/(4 \[Pi]^2);
    ClearAll[tab,actXn,actXnAbs];
    Return[res];
]

 $HistoryLength = 0;
 Do[
    para = Association[{"NMax1D"->700,"NMax3D"->25, "L"-> 2, "mQ"->massSetNat["mPi"]}];
    Print[AbsoluteTiming[calIntE222[para,{0,0,1},{0,0,1}]]];
    ClearAll[para];
    ClearSystemCache[];
,{i,1000}]
```

I use Mathematica Student 11.3 on a 4 kernel Ubunutu system. My knowledge of Mathematica is quite basic.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the nice answer and the informations